# $S$ is spanned by $\vec{v}=(-2, 1, \frac{1}{2}), \vec{w}=(4, -\frac{1}{5}, -1)$ and has the point $P_0=(0, -1, 4)$. Does it contain the given points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I was requested to solve the following problem.

> $S$ is spanned by $\vec{v}=(-2, 1, \frac{1}{2}), \vec{w}=(4, -\frac{1}{5}, -1)$ and contains the point $P_0=(0, -1, 4)$. Does it cross the origin? Does it contain $P_j =(1, -1, \frac{1}{2}), P_k=(0, -\frac{1}{10}, \frac{7}{2}), P_i=(0, \frac{3}{2}, 1)$?

I self study and have no professors to check/correct my answer. I was wondering if someone could provide a bit of insight and tell me whether this is right or wrong (and why in the second case). Here's what I did.

---

The linear equation for the plane can be found by noticing

$$
\vec{n}:=\vec{v} \times \vec{w} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{9}{10} \\ 0 \\ -\frac{18}{5}\end{bmatrix}
$$

From this we have the following linear equation:

$$\begin{align} -\frac{9}{10}(x-0)+0-\frac{18}{5}(z-4) &= 0 \\
-\frac{9}{10}x -\frac{18}{5}z+\frac{72}{5} &=0 \\
-\frac{9}{10}x -\frac{18}{5}z &= -\frac{72}{5}
\end{align}$$

It is clear $x=y=z=0$ do not satisfy this equation ($0 \neq -\frac{72}{5}$). The equation is also not satisfied for $x=1$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=0$ and $z=\frac{7}{2}$, or $x=0$ and $z=1$. So the plane does not cross the origin nor does it contain any of of the given points.

---

I suppose it is strange that none of the points are in the plane (from the point of view of whoever designed the problem, I mean). So I'm guessing I did something wrong. However, after trying for a good while, I couldn't find the flaw in my procedure --if it exists.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your determination of the plane equation looks correct.  It would not be possible for the plane to contain the origin or $ \ P_k \ $ or $ \ P_l \ \ , \ $ since the plane requires $ \ z = \ 4 \ $ for $ \ x \ = \ 0 \   \ . \ $  It also does not contain $ \ P_j \ \ . $  There is no requirement that the poser of the problem ask about any specific points that _do_ lie in the plane:  the choices are that person's prerogative.

Comment: You can simplify the plane equation to $x+4z=16$.